# Отношения в БСП с двоеточием. Неоднозначная трактовка

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сложное-предложение, двоеточие, бсп

"Таинственной, сладостной полное жизни,
Ты *(речь о море)* чисто в присутствии чистом его *(речь о небе)*:
Ты льешься его светозарной лазурью,
Вечерним и утренним светом горишь,
Ласкаешь его облака золотые
И радостно блещешь звездами его".

У меня получается два варианта:

1. бсп с отношениями конкретизации (пояснения), потому что вторую часть можно трактовать как уточнение того, о чем в первой говорится.
   Ты *(речь о море)* чисто в присутствии чистом его *(речь о небе)*:
   **(то есть)** Ты льешься его светозарной лазурью,
   Вечерним и утренним светом горишь,
2. бсп с причинно-следственными отношениями, потому что вторую часть можно трактовать уже как условие, пресуппозицию своего рода для того, о чем говорится в первой части: Ты *(речь о море)* чисто в присутствии чистом его *(речь о небе)*:
   **(потому что)** Ты льешься его светозарной лазурью,
   Вечерним и утренним светом горишь,

Подскажите, пожалуйста, действительно ли здесь может быть два варианта?

Comment: "То есть" не для двоеточия.

Comment: При пояснительных отношениях может стоять... "Муссоны меняют свое направление два раза в год: летом они дуют с моря на сушу, зимой — с суши на море (газ.)";

Comment: Ну здесь не "то есть" (*иными словами*), а "а именно". В правилах указано, что тире, когда "то есть".

Comment: Здесь да, согласна, ближе "а именно". Но читала, что "то есть" там тоже бывает

Comment: "То есть" — это когда то же самое, но другими словами. Двоеточие в таких случаях не ставится.